# How to get currently selected choice from CharField in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to get the currently selected choice from the CharField and use it in **str** method like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    measurement_value = models.FloatField(max_length=200)

    CHOICES = (('a', 'Alpha'), ('b', 'Beta'))
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=CHOICES, default='a')

    def __str__(self):
        """String representation for the foo object."""
        return str(self.measurement_value) + " " + self.choice
```

So for example, if I'd like to add object foo with measurement 10.5 and choice 'a' (Alpha), **str** would return this: "10.5 Alpha"

Currently, the code that I provided returns this: "10.5 a".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the human readable choice name by using instance method [get_{}_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

your example

```
 def __str__(self):
     return str(self.measurement_value) + " " + self.get_choices_display()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried to find the answer for hours!